# How to set requestWhenInUseAuthorization location service in app delegate, and get coordinates in a view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift

All the examples ask for authorization and start updating location in view controller. I want to set that in app delegate and in a view controller return a user's coordinates/location when pressing a button. (I want user coordinates/location accessible in any view controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few options here.

First of all, I would suggest you to implement or use already implemented wrapper for CLLocationManager and call it from anywhere in your code instead of implementing that functionality directly in your AppDelegate ([example of such location manager implementation](https://github.com/sergejp/SPLocationManager)). Such location manager can communicate with the rest of your program using notification center (each view controller subscribe to specific notification which you define) or, for example, via an array of closures (each view controller pass its own closure for handling location update to the instance of location manager, and whenever a user location is updated, location manager calls each closure in the array hence all view controllers requested access to location data will receive that update).

Other than that, let's consider you already implemented access to user location through CLLocationManager in your AppDelegate. In a delegate function which receive updates about location (where you have actual location data), you can send this data to any view controller in your app by doing the following:

**Swift - AppDelegate - using notification center**

```
public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, 
didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let arrayOfLocation = locations as NSArray
    let location = arrayOfLocation.lastObject as! CLLocation
    let coordLatLon = location.coordinate

    var userInfo = [String:AnyObject]()
    userInfo["longitude"] = coordLatLon.longitude
    userInfo["latitude"] = coordLatLon.latitude

    let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    nc.postNotificationName("userLocationUpdate", object: self, userInfo: userInfo)

}
```

**Swift - ViewController - using notification center (define that in viewDidAppear/viewDidLoad, for instance)**

```
let nc = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.locationUpdated(_:)), name: "userLocationUpdate", object: nil)
```

**Swift - ViewController - locationUpdated selector**

```
func locationUpdated(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        //access your data here
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. How would i print() the last coordinate/location in the view controller at any given time? Im still implementing that manager, ill get back to u if i figure it out.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do that. You can either create a static global variable which holds the latest received coordinate (not preferred way and is a bit dirty, in my opinion). Then, you can just create a var in each ViewController where you need it and keep latest gps.If you go with your own LocationManager wrapper as I suggested, then you just define a normal variable which you update whenever a user location updated. Then you can access that variable in any ViewController via referencing to LocationManager instance. Note: LocationManager is singleton so it's quite easy to get your data.

Comment: @user42541 I mean create a public instance variable (userLocationVar, let's say) in LocationManager, update that variable whenever user location updates in delegate function, and in each ViewController you can access LocationManager.sharedInstance.userLocationVar to get latest location.

Comment: DAMN. Best wrapper out there. Worked like a charm. May you have 12 virgins in your next life. Serious tho really good code. TY